# creating htaccess for RESTful (not REST-Like) API seems to be breaking somewhere

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rest, mod-rewrite

Below is the .htaccess I have come up with compiled from various sites I have run in the past, none of which involve RESTful behavior this would be a first. From which I appear to just be breaking it. This htaccess file is in the root directory of the site (ie: www or public_html).

Everything appears in order but its just not doing what I would expect and Im not 100% sure why. I only want the api folder to act as my primary restful services. So any calls to domain.com/api/ should direct through the main handler I will come up with, in this case the index.php in the /api/ folder. Right now all I have in that index.php is a string "Testing" just to test the htaccess rules below. I am not even seeing "Testing" come up in the browser, I've tinkered with it a few different ways and best I got was "No Input file specified" any ideas?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The leading forward slash in your rewrite rule will not be matched. So `domain.com/api/` will never work as you have it now. `RewriteRule` ignores the leading "`/`" in the URI. You can remove the leading `/` before the api folder at the beginning of the rule or use a `?` to make it optional and that way it will work in httpd.conf or an htaccess file. Clear your cache and Try this update.

You should be able to do this this and it would seem a bit simpler.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/?api/(.*)$ /api/index.php [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Then in the index.php you can do

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: did that, going to `domain.com/api/` gives me the index.php file however going to `domain.com/api/foo/bar/bazz` gives me `No input file specified.`

Comment: Does your index.php do routing or use a query string?

Comment: index.php is intent on being used for routing as I want to do a RESTful api not a RESTlike. So to the extent of a query_string going the RESTful route, passing a query string with a method of GET is plausible from the front end. But what I want to do is and I could be wrong is port everything initially through the index.php and create a handler to pull in the other files based on the URI